# Moved libnspr4.so, now cannot sudo

Tags: centos, sudo

When trying to solve another problem. I ended up moving libnspr4.so to my home folder. Now when I try to copy it back to /usr/lib64 folder it 
says

`sudo: unable to dlopen /usr/libexec/sudoers.so: (null)
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins`

I cannot ssh in a separate window aswell
`ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`

I tried using `LD_PRELOAD` but it is not working probably because of the following

> To avoid this mechanism being using as an attack vector for suid/sgid executable binaries, the loader ignores LD_PRELOAD if ruid != euid.

Is there any solution without going into rescue mode?

Comment: I have no idea what that particular library does bit if  you know your root password, `su` has fewer dependancies than `sudo` and might be enough to help you

Answer (score 1):

Login as root to the console if you know the password. Or, start in single user mode. Or, boot the install media to rescue or rebuild.

Try to not modify packaged binaries outside of their package manager. `yum remove` the package you want gone, notice it would remove sudo, and abort.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same error message. It comes as a surprise that `sudo` cannot be used in this situation, but `su root` can. So if you know root password, you can switch to root and reinstall the missing packages.

Comment: Why does it come as a surprise that a binary (transitively) linked to a missing library doesn't work, while a binary not linked to a missing library works?

Comment: @womble Just as @HBrujin said, `su` has fewer dependencies than `sudo`